# Angular 2 write to parent HTML

Tags: angular

I'm displaying table data frequently for a class and so I write out a ton of lines like so:

```html
<td>{{ order.something }}</td>
```

And I have about 15 of those lines.  Instead of copy/pasting that across multiple components that show this data, I wanted to make a new component that just had that as the HTML, and then I could include that component in the `tr` of the `table` with an Input.

Unfortunately that "bundles" those cells into one `td` element in the parent table.  How do I tell Angular 2 to actually push that generated HTML up a level?

Basically the parent `table` has a bunch of other columns as well, and I just want to then use it like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>xyz</td>
  <td>123</td>
  <app-abbrev-table-values [abbrevs]="order"></app-abbrev-table-values>
```

Comment: You might consider adding `:host { display: table-cell; }` to your component's CSS, then remove the `<td>` from the template.

Comment: try putting the directive on a `template` tag. e.g. `<td>123</td><template table-values></template>`

Comment: Can you pls post the html and ts file for component which is supposed to replace the 15 <td>'s and also the html and ts file for one component which will use this common component that replaces 15<td>'s. Basically in the html of a component if you add the selector of the <app-15td-component></app-15td-component> it should display the html which should have just <td>s